# Loop inside a array within a dictionary

Tags: c#

Hi I have a quick question, which is the easiest way to loop inside an array that is within an object in a dictionary using C#?
The dictionary contain groups and groups have an array called tags, I have search for a tag and return a list of groups that contain that tag
I created a solution but it returns too many doubles when I apply it.

```
    List<Programme> toReturn = new List<Programme>();
        // might need to ask getprogramme service to do the iteriation and retun a value
        foreach (Programme programme in programmes.Values)
        {

            if (message.Programme.Tags[0] != null)
            {
                int i;
                int u;

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Programme> entry in programmes)
                {
                    // for (i = 0; i < message.Group.Tags.Length; i++)
                    for (i = 0; i < entry.Value.Tags.Length; i++)
                    //foreach (string i in message.Group.Tags)
                    {
                        for (u = 0; u < message.Programme.Tags.Length; u++)
                        {
                            // Compare the Name of the entry to the Name in the message (string comparison)
                            if (entry.Value.Tags[i].Equals(message.Programme.Tags[u]))
                            {
                                // If we found the group, set the return value and then break from the loop
                                toReturn.Add(programme);

                                break;
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please post your non-working code- we can use that as a starting point

Comment: Can you use LINQ's lambda expressions?

Comment: Do you see how your code has `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Programme> entry in programmes)` nested within `foreach (Programme programme in programmes.Values)`?  That is the cause of your duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use LINQ:

```
var res = groups.Where(g => g.Value.Any(t => t.Equals("search_tag")));
```

Comment: thanks tried to apply it and I need to retun the result trough a message as it is a wcf solution             if (message.Programme.Tags[0] != null)
            {
                var res = programmes.Where(g => g.Value.Tags.Equals(message.Programme.Tags[0]));
                toReturn.Add(res);
            }

Comment: get 2 errors: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,Contracts.Programme>>' to 'Contracts.Programme' 224 30 Programmes
and    Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Contracts.Programme>.Add(Contracts.Programme)' has some invalid arguments  224 17 Programmes

Comment: @user1211929 The reason you get duplicates is that you are breking out the inner loop, when you need to break out of both innermost loops. You can do it, for example, by assigning `i = entry.Value.Tags.Length` right before your `break` statement.